# Is this a valid way of proving that the preimage of an open set is open?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to understand the proof on page ten of this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277748677_Homeomorphism_between_Sphere_and_Cube) that $\phi^{-1}(\beta)$ is open for an open set $\beta$. From what I understand, one way of proving this would be to show that for each $x \in \phi^{-1}(\beta)$, there is some neighbourhood of $x$, where a neighbourhood is a set containing an open set containing $x$, such that the neighbourhood is a subset of $\phi^{-1}(\beta)$. That is, $$
x \in N_x \subset \phi^{-1}(\beta) \quad (1).
$$
From what I understand, they show that $$
x \in \phi^{-1}(N_{\phi(x)}) \subset \phi^{-1}(\beta) \quad (2).
$$
My question is: does (2) imply (1) given the context ($\phi$ is bijective, $\phi: S^2 \to C^3$, $\beta$ is open in the relative Euclidean topology of the surface of the cube etc)? Also is it more generally the case that $f^{-1}(N_{f(x)})$ is a neighbourhood for $x$?

Comment: The linked paper is clearly written by people who don't know almost anything about topology, even claiming they need to prove the cube is a topological space (this is trivial; it's a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ so inherits the subspace topology). If you want to get an explicit homeomorphism, just note both spaces are compact and Hausdorff so any continuous bijection will be a homeomorphism. The map is then obvious: map every point $x$ on the cube to $\frac{x}{\| x \|}$.

Comment: This is clearly a bijection (you could prove this by hand if you really want by considering the faces, or just note the cube with it's interior is convex and so every line intersects the cube along a line segment. Restricting the boundary, the only line segments that remain don't extend to lines passing through origin, so lines passing through origin become a pair of antipodal points) and is clearly continuous (it's the quotient of two continuous functions that are never zero) so is a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is not valid. The authors show that $\phi$ is bijective in the previous step, which seems mostly fine. To show continuity, they assume $\beta$ open in $C^3$ that contains some point, say $y$. By bijectivity of $\phi$, $y$ has a unique pre-image $x = \phi^{-1} (y)$. They then claim that, given a  neighborhood $N$ of $y$ in $C^3$ with $N \subseteq \beta$, the preimage $\phi^{-1} (N)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $S^2$. This last part isn't justified, however, since it precisely relies on the fact $\phi$ is continuous (in particular, at $x$), which is what was to be proved! The argument is circular.

A good indicator that something is not quite right is that no properties specific to the function $\phi$ were used in the proof.

It is not enough for the function to be bijective. Letting $a = 1 \times 0 \times 0$ and $b = -1 \times 0 \times 0$ be antipodal points of $S^2$, consider the bijection $\phi' : S^2 \to C^3$ given by

$$\phi' (x) = \begin{cases}
\phi (x) & x \notin \{ a, b \} \\
\phi (b) & x = a \\
\phi (a) & x = b
\end{cases}$$

where $\phi$ is the original proposed bijection. It is easy to check that $\phi'$ is bijective; this follows naturally from the bijectivity of $\phi$. Consider the point $x = a$, which is mapped to $y = \phi' (a) = \phi (b) = b$. The subset $N$ of $C^3$ consisting of points with a negative first coordinate is a neighborhood of $y$. Note that $\phi^{-1} (N)$ consists of the point $a$ along with all the points in $S^2$ with a negative first coordinate except $b$. This collection is clearly *not* a neighborhood of $x = a$.